# Is there a way to close file upload dialog using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I made a fiddle for your quick understood.

https://jsfiddle.net/bexoss/hdr5824a/7/

Is there a way to close file dialog using JavaScript? 
I tried to send `ESC` key but the dialog is not dimissed.

```
<input id="input_file" type="file" />
<div></div>


<script>
// jQuery lib included in somewhere 

$(document).on('click', '#input_file', function(e){
    $('div').append('File dialog is opened. <br/>')

    setTimeout(function(){
        var esc = $.Event("keydown", { keyCode: 27 });
        $('div').append('Escape key sent.<br/>')
        $("body").trigger(esc); 
    }, 2000)
})

</script>
```

Comment: @CertainPerformance Okay, I added code. Thanks.

Comment: `ESC` will not work here as you trigger ti in your thread but the file dialog is browser's part and is out of your sandbox.

Comment: On second thought, you cannot. File dialog gives access to file storage. JS being in sandbox does not have access to and should not even have. So to answer your question, no. there is no way to do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  There is no way using Javascript due to security issues.  This applies to all browsers and all versions.

If you want to trigger a key stroke, it would have to be native on the operating system, and not through the DOM.

This is also why the dialog box is different for the same browser on different OS. The dialog comes from the OS, via the internal API, not the browser.

This also applies to `window.alert` and `window.prompt`

Comment: Though it answers the question, not sure if it should be a comment or answer. Holding my vote as not sure

Comment: I have tried this.  I AM  sure.  I had to run a Java service and listen on a socket, then trigger a native click to close a popup triggered by the browser once.

Comment: I completely agree that this is not possible via just JS. Just unsure that should we answer it or just comment it as it falls in that gray zone

Comment: Since it answers the question, it should be posted as an answer

Comment: But the problem is even though I use kind of `robotjs` to send keystroke to server side, that's not working

Comment: Plus I could not keep updating my answer if I used a comment!

Comment: The server can't send a keystroke on the client unless the server is running on the client.

Comment: Actually I use `puppeteer`, even I send using puppeteer's send key features it's not working haha... maybe I should find another workaround, Thanks